# What part of speech is 到 (to) when used in 两只饿到眼绿的老鼠正在房梁上打架?

Tags: grammar, usage, meaning-in-context

I was having trouble with the sentence

> 两只饿到眼绿的老鼠正在房梁上打架

because I could not understand the usage of 到 here. After I spent some time thinking I figure the meaning is that the rats were hungry ***to*** the extent that their eyes turned green (a metaphor of some sort?) but if that is indeed the case, what would you call this type of word? In English I believe the word "to" used in this way is called a preposition but I haven't seen anything online about the usage of prepositions in Chinese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially correct. Here, 到 is a preposition that, depending on context, can represent "to," "(up) until," or "up to."

e.g. 到目前为止 : up until this moment

工作到天亮了 : work until the sky becomes light

从周一到周四 : From Monday to Thursday

In your particular example, there seems to be an implied “的程度" at the end of the descriptor which is omitted, i.e. one can write 两只饿到眼绿**的程度**的老鼠正在房染上打架, and in order to prevent a sentence from being clunky, this has been omitted since it's clear from context what is being said here.

Answer (score 2):

I like that, "so hungry their eyes were green", haven't heard that before!

两只饿到眼绿的老鼠正在房梁上打架
2 hungry that eyes green 的 mice just in the room roof-beams fight
Two mice, both so hungry that their eyes were green, were fighting on a roof-beam.

Maybe it should be "饿的眼放绿光". Anyway, 饿到眼绿 means very very hungry.

饿到眼绿
hungry until eyes green  到 = until
so hungry (their) eyes went green

"饿的眼放绿光"
hungry that eyes send out green light

A quick search gave me [this answer](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/507048823.html). Not sure if it is accurate. I can't find a source for "饿的眼放绿光" . I'm sure someone here knows.

晚上狼的眼睛看起来是绿色的，说饿的眼放绿光，其实就是说饿得向狼一样，见到食物就像饿狼看见人一样。

Answer (score 1):

Other examples I can think of:

`红到发紫` --this is often used to describe someone is very popular

`富到流油` -- this is used to describe someone is very rich

In all these cases, 到 can be replaced with 得.

To remember some use cases is a good way to remember how to use the word.